# how to fill twice id from routes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

i try to fill twice id in url, but when i send params twice id just one id fill the url id.

My route :

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :stores
    get "/:id/new_items"=> 'stores#new_items', as: :store_new_items
    post "/:id/create_items"=> 'stores#create_items', as: :store_create_items
    get "/:id/show_items/:id"=> 'stores#show_items', as: :store_show_items
    get "/:id/items/:id/new_items_sub" => 'stores#new_items_sub', as: :store_new_items_sub
    post "/:id/items/:id/create_items_sub" => 'stores#create_items_sub', as: :store_create_items_sub
    get "/:id/items/:id/show_items_sub/:id" => 'stores#show_items_sub', as: :store_show_items_sub
  end
```

my view :

```
<%= link_to "add new items", admin_store_new_items_sub_path(@store.id, @items.id), :class=> "btn" %>
```

i hope my url like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/#{store.id}/items/#{items.id}/new_items_sub
```

but i get same id like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/#{store.id}/items/#{store.id}/new_items_sub
```

please tell me when i'm wrong? thanks

Comment: have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: wow works properly, thanks you @NitinJ

Comment: can i make that answer :)

Comment: posted take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create neseted routes for that .have a look at 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

for example

```
resources :publishers do
  resources :magazines do
    resources :photos
   end
end
```

will accept routes `/publishers/1/magazines/2/photos/3`

Answer (score 0):

Your params should be unique, so you can't pass more than one different `:id` params. Instead. you can do something like:

```
get '/:store_id/show_items/:id', as: :store_show_items
```

and in view:

```
<%= link_to 'show items', store_show_items_path(@store.id, @item.id) %>
```

Also, you should read more about [Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) and [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in Rails, there's probably no need to complicate your life by creating each route independently.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor this to use nested routes like this (you may have to change controller method names):

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :stores do
    resources :items, :only => [:new, :create, :show] do
      resources :subs, :only => [:new, :create, :show]
    end
  end
end
```

This would give you a few url helpers like this: `new_store_item_sub_path(@store.id, @item.id)` for the new action and `store_item_sub_path(@store.id, @item.id, @sub.id)` for the show action.

Run `rake routes` to see what helpers and routes you have access to.

[Have a look here to find out more about nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be DRYed up significantly. Hopefully this works; might need some tweaking:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :stores do

        member do 
            get :new_items, as: :store_new_items
            post :create_items, as: :store_create_items
        end

        get "show_items/:id"=> 'stores#show_items', as: :store_show_items

        resources :items do 
            get :new_items_stub => 'stores#new_items_sub', as: :store_new_items_sub
            post :create_items_stub => 'stores#create_items_sub', as: :store_create_items_sub
            get "show_items_sub/:id" => 'stores#show_items_sub', as: :store_show_items_sub
        end
     end
  end
```

Uses [Member Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) (see 2.10) & [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

---

**Nested Resources**

The crux of your issue is that you're trying to pass the `:id` param twice

Fortunately, Rails has a solution to this, in the form of Nested Resources. These work by taking the "parent" `id` and prepending a singular prefix, such as `:store_id`, allowing you to use the `:id` param for another set of methods